# Generate Junit test results from a build.xml in a android project

Tags: android, junit, build.xml

I am trying to run and publish my JUnit tests in HTML using a build.xml file calling the JUnit target but it doesn't seem to work.

here is how my build.xml looks like:

```
<target name="Unity Agent SDK Test ">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    <echo message="making directory" />
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="yes">
        <formatter type="xml" />
        <test name="com.kc.AllTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <test name="com.kc.unity.agent.util.ActivityOneTestcase" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <test name="com.kc.unity.agent.util.FaceBookRestManagerTestCase" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
        <test name="com.kc.unity.agent.util.OAuthManagerTestCase" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />

        <classpath refid="Unity Agent SDK Test.classpath" />

        <bootclasspath>
            <path refid="run.Unity Agent SDK Test (1).bootclasspath" />
        </bootclasspath>
    </junit>
    <echo message="junit finished" />
</target>
<target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

Here is the error I get:

```
Unity Agent SDK Test :
     [echo] making directory
    [junit] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    [junit]  at junit.framework.TestResult.<init>(TestResult.java:4)
    [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:315)
    [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:911)
    [junit]  at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:768)

BUILD FAILED
C:\xxxxxxxxx\Android\Projects\Unity Agent SDK Test\build.xml:85: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

In android you have to run test cases with android instrumentation (adb shell am instrument ...) they cannot be run with junit launcher which is done by ant task.

Please take a look at
http://code.neenbedankt.com/android-junit-results-in-hudson

I haven't reviewed that myself, yet but I believe you can re-use it.